# What's the name of this tool?

Tags: tools

What's the name of this tool? Is it a screw driver, or a gun that shoots nails to wood, wall, etc?

How can I use it safely?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Voting to close because https://www.google.com/search?q=wx245l.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a [WORX WX254L SD Semi-Automatic Power Screw Driver with 12 Driving Bits](http://WORX%20WX254L%20SD%20Semi-Automatic%20Power%20Screw%20Driver%20with%2012%20Driving%20Bits)