# Unscrew a screw in a hole

Tags: screws, screwdriver

There is a screw in a hole in my laptop. I fail to unscrew it with a screw driver. How can I unscrew it?

The end of the handle of the screwdriver is loose, and what is the looseness supposed to be used for?

Thanks.

[image]

My tools

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The loose end is for your index finger to press the screwdriver against the screw and thus provide the second fixed point for its axis while the thumb and the middle finger are turning the screwdriver. It allows the most precise operation of all manual screwdrivers.

I would also speculate that this might not be the right tool for the work. This kind of screwdrivers are for precision work where you need to be very exact in where you touch your device and exert a very limited force. You need a regular screwdriver, which would allow to exert higher torque and at the same time press stronger along the screwdriver/screw axis to prevent them from losing each other.

For the screw you want to turn, you need one of the bits in your second photo, in the holder with the word "Poholy" on it, number 5...7 from the left in the photo (4...6 if you turn it upside up). Take the one that fits the screw best. You will also need a handle, which is missing in your photo. It looks something like the blue one in [this photo](http://gloimg.dealsmachine.com/ba/2015/201512/source-img/1449857039012-P-3549562.jpg).

You can use the electrical screwdriver from Worx that you showed in [another post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90568/whats-the-name-of-this-tool), but choose the correct bit and as low torque as possible to start with. With the electrical screwdriver, it's very easy to damage the screw cap.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a right tool for unscrewing the screw in the hole http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90568/whats-the-name-of-this-tool ?

Comment: @Tim, can you mark with a circle or arrow the screw you are having troubles with? It looks like you have all the needed tools but I am not sure what the trouble is exactly. I would avoid using the electric screwdriver in this case, it's more for assembling furniture or hanging shelves.

Comment: The screw deep in the hole in the bottom left corner of the laptop, below the screw driver.

Comment: picture updated.

Comment: @Tim, answer updated.

Comment: Yes, the handle is not shown in the second picture. The bits are too thick to reach the screw in the hole, so I used the screw driver in the first picture., but was unable to drive the screw because it was too tight.

Comment: @Tim, now the story is clear. It happens all the time, so I also have a separate set of simple screwdrivers for such situations. One last thing you can try before getting another tool is take your precision screwdriver and, while pressing it against the screw with one hand, try to turn it using the pliers I also see in your set. They are not the most suitable for this job, but may work. Just make sure the tip of the screwdriver is not too small for the screw, otherwise you may kill the latter.

Comment: What does "turn it using the pliers" look like?

Comment: @Tim, grab it with the pliers instead of your thumb and middle fingers. But I would rather buy a dedicated screwdriver in your place. They a couple of Euros and are really useful in the household.

Comment: what's a dedicated screwdriver here?

Comment: @Tim, just a screwdriver that fits this specific screw and hole (i.e. depth, diameter). Take you laptop to a local DIY or electrical store, they'll show you. You can also buy a set, it's cheaper per tool. I have something like [this](http://www.spear-and-jackson.com/product/new-products/vde-screwdriver-set-6pc). (Note that these specific screwdrivers are electrically isolated, meaning they are thicker for most of the length than the non-isolated ones. So make sure to check what you buy fits your hole.)